# Performance of modifying an array in an object: to use a variable, or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, variables, object

Consider the following JavaScript global object:

```
var obj = { key1: [ 'data1', 'data2', ... ], key2: [ 'data1, 'data2', ... ], ... }
```

Assume I have a function that needs to modify the array assigned to a specific key in `obj`. Is it more efficient to use a local variable for my computations and modify the array at the end of my function, or should I be modifying the array directly, since it's not deep within the object?

In essence, I am asking which function is more efficient:

```
function local_variable() {
    var foo = [];
    $( selector ).map(function() {
        foo.push( $( this ).val() );
    });
    obj[ keyx ] = foo;
}
```

versus

```
function global_object() {
    obj[ keyx ] = [];
    $( selector ).map(function() {
        obj[ keyx ].push( $( this ).val() );
    });
}
```

As always, if there is an even better way to do what these functions do, please enlighten me.

Comment: While both of the functions "work", it's an inappropriate use of the `.map` function. Maybe this helps to understand it better: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_function.

Comment: The question is moot. You are using the map method wrong. It's used to loop one array and return another, but you are using it as the each method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsPerf comes with help](http://jsperf.com/object-access-testcase).

Apparently, accessing object's property each time (`global_object`) is slower that data acquisition and further assignment (`local_variable`).

However, as you see, it depends on the optimization strategy used by the particular browser (Firefox, almost equal).

Answer (score 3):

```
function adeneos_object() {
    obj[ keyx ] = $.map($( selector ),function(el){return el.value;});
}
```

Comment: This is how you use the map method.